# How to convert DoubleVector to IntVector in Java Vector API?

Tags: java, vectorization, simd

The bellow Java Vector API code has a DoubleVector filled with doubles, named "A1".
I am trying to convert this DoubleVector (A1) to IntVector (RESULT), so far unsuccessful.

```
    double[] v1 = {10237, 10709, 11340, 11468, 11771, 12003, 12196, 12456, 13904, 14557, 14636, 14811, 15337, 15468, 15719, 15990};
    double[] v2 = {150, 171, 180, 183, 184, 289, 301, 306, 358, 449, 486, 539, 567, 605, 643};
    int[] result = new int[v1.length];
    var species = DoubleVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED;
    for (int index = 0; index < v1.length; index += species.length()) {
        var V1 = DoubleVector.fromArray(species, v1, index);
        var V2 = DoubleVector.fromArray(species, v2, index);
        DoubleVector A1 = V1.div(V2).pow(2);
        //Create IntVector RESULT by the convertion of DoubleVector A1 to IntVector.
        RESULT.intoArray(result, index);
    }
```

EDIT 1:
After more research on the subject, the updated code is:

```
    double[] v1 = {10237, 10709, 11340, 11468, 11771, 12003, 12196, 12456, 13904, 14557, 14636, 14811, 15337, 15468, 15719, 15990};
    double[] v2 = {150, 171, 180, 183, 184, 289, 301, 306, 358, 449, 486, 539, 567, 605, 643};
    int[] result = new int[v1.length];
    var species = DoubleVector.SPECIES_PREFERRED;
    for (int index = 0; index < v1.length; index += species.length()) {
        var V1 = DoubleVector.fromArray(species, v1, index);
        var V2 = DoubleVector.fromArray(species, v2, index);
        DoubleVector A1 = V1.div(V2).pow(2);
        //Create IntVector RESULT by the convertion of DoubleVector A1 to IntVector.
        IntVector RESULT = A1.convert(VectorOperators.D2I, index).reinterpretAsInts();    // <--- I need help to write this line correctly.
        RESULT.intoArray(result, index);
    }
```

There is an error message related to the size difference between double and int, that says: `bad part number 4 converting Species[double, 4, S_256_BIT] -> Species[int, 8, S_256_BIT] (lanes are contracting by 2)`.

Edit 2:
When I run the code with the this line:

```
    IntVector RESULT = A1.convert(VectorOperators.D2I, 0).reinterpretAsInts();    // "0" instead of "index"
```

Then the error message changes to: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 12 out of bonds for length 9`

Comment: Do you think it's a good strategy to just hope that someone who knows that unnamed API comes along and happens to read this?

Comment: @g00se, this is a preview API in the JDK itself, so not some random library.  That said: how would you expect this to work without vectorization?  Going from eight byte doubles to four byte ints is going to complicate things with the vectorization API, which needs things to be the same size or explicitly converted.  Read the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.incubator.vector/jdk/incubator/vector/DoubleVector.html#convert(jdk.incubator.vector.VectorOperators.Conversion,int)) on the function you'll need to do conversion.

Comment: Right. But even so

Comment: I don’t program Java, but note that class has `convert` and `convertShape` methods. Pretty sure you need to call one of them, with some arguments.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, after more research on the subject,, I have just updated the code.  Although I have added a line of code to convert DoubleVector to IntVector,, there is an error message related to the size difference between double and int. Could you please help me write this conversion from DoubleVector to IntVector appropriately?

Comment: Putting `index` into the part number of the `convert` won't work (you have a vector contraction here so the valid part numbers are small negative numbers and zero, not positive), shouldn't it just be zero?

Comment: @harold,, If I write `IntVector RESULT = A1.convert(VectorOperators.D2I, 0).reinterpretAsInts();`  (with zero, instead of "index"), then the error message changes to: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:: Index 12 out of bonds for length 9`.